# Excel Button or Drop-down headers Language Selector

Tags: excel, vba

I have these 4 headers in Excel.

Ex:

```
1  First row english  Name                                  Description english
2  Second row French  Nom                                   Description french
3  Third row english  name complete                         this is a description
4  Fourth row French  name french complete                  une description francaise
```

I would like to create a language selector button or a drop down list selector which will only display if i select English = display headers 1 and 3  or If i select french it display the headers 2 and 4.

How can I do that in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a procedure that hides all rows and then shows only the rows of the specified language:

```
Public Sub ShowOlny(Optional ByVal Language As String)
    'hide all rows
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    'show specific language
    If Language = "English" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("2:2,4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Language = "French" Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("1:1,3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else 'show all
        ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    'scroll into view
    ActiveWindow.ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 1, 1
End Sub
```

And call it like:

```
Sub test()
    ShowOlny "English" 'shows only row 2 and 4

    ShowOlny "French"  'shows only row 1 and 3

    ShowOlny           'shows all rows
End Sub
```

---

Altenatively make sure you data is formatted as table and has a column `Language` as below.
Then you can [use slicers to filter data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-slicers-to-filter-data-249f966b-a9d5-4b0f-b31a-12651785d29d) (no VBA code needed):

[image]

Comment: Nice one, especially the `Slicer` and [ScrollIntoView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.window.scrollintoview) parts.

Answer (score 2):

### Language Selector (Button)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub toggleLanguage()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const btnName As String = "Button 1"
    Dim Lang(1) As Variant
    Lang(0) = Array("English", 1, 3)
    Lang(1) = Array("French", 2, 4)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim btn As Button: Set btn = ws.Buttons(btnName)
    Dim English As Boolean

    If btn.Characters.Text = Lang(0)(0) Then
        English = True
    End If
    btn.Characters.Text = Lang(Abs(English))(0)
    Union(ws.Rows(Lang(Abs(English))(1)), _
          ws.Rows(Lang(Abs(English))(2))).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Union(ws.Rows(Lang(Abs(Not English))(1)), _
          ws.Rows(Lang(Abs(Not English))(2))).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

### Edit

- This version allows to select more rows.
- In this example one would expect that row `11` will be visible all the
  time, but it is always hidden which could possibly be exploited. To get the
  normal behavior just switch the two consecutive lines starting with
  `Curr =`.
- I also added the great `ScrollIntoView` part from
  [Pᴇʜ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219613/p%e1%b4%87%ca%9c)'s
  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210228/excel-button-or-drop-down-headers-language-selector/62211662#62211662).

[image]
[image]

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub toggleLanguage()

    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const btnName As String = "Button 1"
    Dim Lang(1) As Variant
    Lang(0) = Array("Select English", 1, 3, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)
    Lang(1) = Array("Select French", 2, 4, 10, 11, 12, 16, 20)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim btn As Button: Set btn = ws.Buttons(btnName)
    Dim English As Boolean

    If btn.Characters.Text = Lang(0)(0) Then
        English = True
    End If
    Dim Curr As Long
    Curr = Abs(English)
    btn.Characters.Text = Lang(Curr)(0)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim rng As Range, i As Long, doHide As Boolean
    Curr = Abs(Not English): doHide = False: GoSub hideOrUnhide
    Curr = Abs(English): doHide = True: GoSub hideOrUnhide
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Windows(wb.Name).ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 1, 1

Exit Sub

hideOrUnhide:
    Set rng = ws.Rows(Lang(Curr)(1))
    For i = 2 To UBound(Lang(Curr))
        Set rng = Union(rng, ws.Rows(Lang(Curr)(i)))
    Next i
    rng.EntireRow.Hidden = doHide
    Return

End Sub
```